# Scanner is not stopping

Tags: java, collections, io, arraylist

Please have a look at the following code. It is my attempt to manage the given numbers in ascending order.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TurboSort
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {

        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList();        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(scan.hasNextInt())
        {
            numbers.add(scan.nextInt());
        }


        Collections.sort(numbers);

        System.out.println(numbers);
    }
}
```

insert the input as 2,1,6,7,3

Hit enter.

Now, the scanner hasn't exited from the while loop because it is not giving any output. What am I doing here wrong? Even if you manage to get it, the output is surrounded by brackets like " [1] [2] [3] ". Why is that? Is that is because I didn't call 'Integer.parseInt()' ?. Please help me with those 2 questions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This loop will never exit (as long as you enter integers) as there is no `break` condition

```
while(scan.hasNextInt()){
  numbers.add(scan.nextInt());
}
```

If you want your loop to stop, say for example you need to acquire only 5 integers then you could do this:

```
while(scan.hasNextInt()){
  numbers.add(scan.nextInt());
  if(numbers.size() == 5) break;
}
```

Comment: that's not true, the loop will stop at the moment you enter non-int symbol.

Comment: @hovanessyan Right, thanks for the pointer. I updated my answer

Comment: @hovanessyan that code works, it is just another example of a condition to end the loop

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I appreciate it. :) I was actually trying to solve this http://www.codechef.com/problems/TSORT

But I gave up that site; There are very less Java people because most of their challenges cannot be done in Java because of the time limit. Good for C people anyway

Answer (score 4):

The result of hitting enter will be a line separator, whose characters are treated as delimiters (by default, see [Character.isWhitespace()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29)) and are skipped. Thus the `Scanner` is waiting for further input, which never arrives and the `hasNextInt()` will block. Enter something which is not an integer, like a `.` for example, to cause the loop to terminate:

> 1 2 5 3 7 .

Answer (score 2):

The Scanner continues to scan until the end of input has reached, or until it fails to read (e.g. when a non integer is detected in the text).

Hit ctrl + D after you hit enter.
You can separate the numbers any white space.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the input on only 1 line like `2,1,6,7,3`, probably would be easier to use `nextLine()` of the scanner:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
String consoleInput = scan.nextLine();
```

This will terminate the scanner, once you hit enter. At this point, you have the input in a String, you have to parse that string and get out all the numbers.

Also note that you have forgotten to parameterize your ArrayList().

Here's a possible adaptation of your source code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    String consoleInput = scan.nextLine();

    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();


    if (consoleInput.length() > 0 && consoleInput.contains(",")) {

      String[] numbersAsStrings = consoleInput.split(",");

      for (String tNumberAsString : numbersAsStrings) {
        try {
          int tNumber = Integer.parseInt(tNumberAsString);

          numbers.add(tNumber);

        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
          System.out.println(tNumberAsString + " is not a number");
        }
      }

      Collections.sort(numbers);

      System.out.println(numbers);

    } else {
      System.out.println("Nothing to sort!");
      System.out.println(numbers);
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work. You just need to add a way to break out of the loop. It also is a good idea to keep your scanned value in a local variable in case you need to reference it again.

maybe add:

```
while(scan.hasNextInt()){
    int i=scan.nextInt();
        if(i==-1)
            break;

    numbers.add(i);
}
```

Comment: the loop will end if you fail the "scan.hasNextInt()" condition - like- enter "exit" for example or a '.' as suggested.

Comment: @honanessyan yes it will, I was just trying to show an alternative approach (to make it more explicit).

Comment: Yes, the code will work, but I think the whole point is to let the user enter as many numbers as they like. (I am talking about number.size()==5

Comment: yes except for -1. It is just an example of another way to break out of the loop...   I am assuming that this is a homework question and the person is new to Java. Keeping that in mind, it is good to see alternative approaches. For example, if the person needed to include strings it would be much harder to see a way to break out of the loop if they tried to enter a non-String.